# GcmIntentService Open fragment after click notification

Tags: android, android-fragments

anyone can help me to construct my code.

i want to open fragment after click notification.

here is my code.

in my **GcmIntentService** i have this code.

```
private void sendNotification(String ttl,String msg, String type, String src) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("menuFragment", "favoritesMenuItem");

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);


            Bitmap bitmap_logo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.m);
            Bitmap bitmap_image=getBitmapFromURL(src);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setContentTitle(ttl)
                             .setContentText(msg)
                            .setLargeIcon(bitmap_logo)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.m)
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                                    .bigPicture(bitmap_image)
                                    .setBigContentTitle(ttl)
                                    .setSummaryText(msg))
                            .setAutoCancel(true);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

and in my **activity** this is where get extras.

```
String menuFragment = getIntent().getStringExtra("menuFragment");

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuFragment, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (menuFragment != null)
            {
                if (menuFragment.equals("favoritesMenuItem"))
                {
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, ContactusFragment.newInstance(customersid))
                            .commit();
                }
            }
```

but the extra is not working.

please help me.

Comment: where are you calling this code in onCreate() of mainactivity

Comment: Returns an existing or new PendingIntent matching the given parameters. May return null only if FLAG_NO_CREATE has been supplied. Look this:http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent, int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

Add this code,

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationIntent, 0);
```

instead of

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
```

Comment: you should face issue in future notification (PendingIntent works correctly for the first notification but incorrectly for the rest ) as mention here https://androidhub.wordpress.com/tag/pending-intent-flags/

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, pending intents are references to already stored
intents. A pending intent uses the input intent as a key to locate
previously established pending intent for this intent. The key to
locate this does not include the "extras". All other parts of an
intent participate in this uniqueness. Try this

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

For detail visit https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Fb5fJd_Hc-w

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
```

with

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```